# Dataflow template - Cloud Storage Text to Cloud Pub/Sub (Stream) does not scale

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, autoscaling

I have set up a google dataflow template streaming job where i am trying to push each message from GCS to pubsub. The job does not autoscale and it gives out of memory exception after reading some GB of files. I want to read more than 5 TB data from GCS. The strange part is that the job does not stop and keeps reading but because of the memory exception, i am not able to figure out if its reading all the records or not. Can someone help on this ?

Comment: Show us the code you have tried. Without that it's almost impossible to help with this.

Comment: Are you using the Stream or Batch version of the template? The stream version makes use of . watchForNewFiles.
Also do you have tens of thousands of files or more in the GCS bucket or a smaller number of very large files?

Comment: I am using streaming pipeline and it has lots of small files in gcs bucket. The total size of all files is more than 5 TB. Yes it watches for 10 seconds but in this case,the new files come at a less frequency but I have to process lot of historical files which are already present in bucket and that's when I am getting this error. There is no sample code to it as it is just using template given in GCP console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Max workers` in the template to let the autoscaling scale the workers.

Also, I would recommend opening a ticket with GCP as the job should just be slow and should not go OOM in this case. The investigation will require access to the job logs.